# Is there a way to return custom string response instead of return next.handle(req); in angular interceptor?

Tags: angular, interceptor

I'm using angular interceptor and cached data, so I need sometimes to return already cached data instead of going to server to get this data. I tried with Observable.apply(data); but it doesn't work.

```
const request = req.clone();
if(condition){
   var text = window.localStorage.getItem(something);
   //HERE I NEED TO RETURNE TEXT
} else { 
   return next.handle(req);
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, `next.handle()` will call the next interceptor in the chain, which will call the next and so on until it reaches the observable where the http request is sent. So, I think you could avoid making the request and using the other interceptors by simply returning an observable with your cached data.

Comment: do you have any example of observable?

Comment: I guess `of(yourCachedData)` would work?

Comment: I will try it now, thank you!

Comment: No worries! Here's an article that explores the HttpClientModule: [Exploring the HttpClientModule in Angular](https://indepth.dev/exploring-the-httpclientmodule-in-angular/)